# Not matching an optional colon at the end of the strings with a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to create a regex for extracting all string from the beginning to the end of the string except the colon (:) at the end of the string.

The strings are:

```
ORA-06550: line 10, column 33:
ORA-20000: Schema "TEST" does not exist or insufficient privileges
PLS-00201: identifier 'A' must be declared:
```

In the one regular expression in the Perl language I want to capture following strings:

```
ORA-06550: line 10, column 33
ORA-20000: Schema "TEST" does not exist or insufficient privileges
PLS-00201: identifier 'A' must be declared
```

So far, I have the following regex ([see online](http://regex101.com/r/rH6mC9/2))::

```
/^(.*)(?::)?$/gm
```

My problem is how to construct a regex that will get rid of the colon from the first and third string and simultaneously capturing all the second string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this non-greedy regex:

```
/^(.*?):?$/gm
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL7lI9/1)

Comment: There is no need using a lazy quantifier. Its very slow and unnecessary.

Comment: Not this `^.+(?<!:$)`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to extract everything, you can just remove the colon at the end of the string.

```
$str =~ s/:$//;
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest regex I can think of is

```
   /(.+):$/
```

So to edit the buffer in place:

```
  $buffer =~ s/(.+):$/$1/;
```

But you could also consider:

```
   chop $buffer if $buffer =~ /:$/;
```

which looks for the trailing colon, and chops it off when found.

Comment: I think he has possible lines without the colon.

Comment: Hence the 'if and chop' solution. Not every solution requires a s/// operator with a complex regex with a zero-width look behind modifier. Some time and if/then suffices and is more clear. In fact, 'chop if ends in colon' is not only more clear, but actually reads like the intent of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
@data = <DATA>;
@remove = grep{s/(:$)?//g} @data;
print "@remove\n";

__DATA__
ORA-06550: line 10, column 33:
ORA-20000: Schema "TEST" does not exist or insufficient privileges
PLS-00201: identifier 'A' must be declared:
```

This bit of code remove the **:** from your data. I added the **?** to match preceding character 0 or 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest and simplest way to do it

```
/^.+(?<!:$)/mg
```